# Since which value integers stop being cached and reused in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, caching, integer, internals

In Python 3:

```
>> X = 42
>> Y = 42
>> X is Y
True

>> X = 2 ** 20
>> Y = 2 ** 20
>> X is Y
False

>> X = 2 ** 2
>> Y = 2 ** 2
>> X is Y
True
```

What is the precise value for integers since which I start getting False instead of True when I state "X is Y"? ( Assuming I'm running standard Python 3 ).

Comment: This sounds like the kind of problem a program should solve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **interpreter** dependent (i.e. there are no specifications that require such caching). But as far as I know the `python` interpreter has a cache for integers up to and including **256**. Furthermore values up to and including **-5** are cached as well. So the **range is -5 to 256** (both included), like written in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/long.html):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between **-5 and 256** (..)

You thus better **never use reference equality** to check whether two integers are equal, **always use `==`**. This is also useful if you for instance would compare an `int` against a numpy `int16`. If you use reference checks, the following will fail:

```
>>> np.int16(12) is 12
False
>>> np.int16(12) == 12
True
```